# Run a function after a form has been submitted

Tags: javascript, html

I want to execute some javascript **after** a form has been submitted. (I want it to clear the contents of some of the input fields, and maybe print to the html page some information from the previous submission)

I'm already using `<input type="submit" onclick="appendRedundancy()" value="Submit">` to have the computer do some magic before the form is sent off. If I tell `appendRedundancy()` to clean the form, I am worried it will clean the form **before** sending it off.

If I add `<script> cleanForm(); </script>` after `<form>...</form>`

It executes it before the form has been filled in by the human.

How do I dictate the order of events?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just call cleanForm at the very end of appendRedundancy? Why are you worried about trying code. Just try it and see if it works, if it doesn't, it's not gonna kill you....

Comment: you can't do anything after a form is submitted unless you submit the form via ajax.

Comment: Because appendRedundancy() is used to add information to be sent off. it makes no sense if the same function that adds it then removes it.

Comment: @aName Says who? If you're concerned about keeping functions distinct, why not just create a new function that calls `appendRedundancy()` then your `cleanForm()` and tie THAT to `onclick`?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Can I have the the form set a flag? then have something in the HTML constantly check if the flag has been triggered? Seems hacky, but if it works...

Comment: @aName - no because after the form is submitted the user has loaded a different page. you could use a serviceworker do do stuff after a form is submitted.. or you can do something as the form is being submitted - but never after, unless you use ajax.

Comment: When the page loads, test to see if it's loading because of the previous form's submission or not. If it is, clear out the fields.

Comment: Are you intercepting the `submit` event and submitting via AJAX? Or just allowing the form to submit naturally? Because if you aren't submitting via AJAX, then what you are asking for is not possible, because the page will reload to the `action` of the form. If you are using AJAX, then just hook into the onsuccess callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on submit event

```
<input type="submit" onsumbit="appendRedundancy()" value="Submit">
```

example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Another way is you post via ajax and get it by success function

```html
   $(document).ready(function(){
 $("p").click(function(){

$.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: 'url.php',
data: $("#your_form").serialize(),
success: function(data) {
//do something here 
 }
});
});
 });
```

Comment: onsubmit will do stuff before the form is submitted. op wants to do stuff after the form is submitted. he even made the word **after** bold.

Comment: Other way is he use ajax and get into sucess function, I will update

Comment: The first of your two options is wrong. It'll fire BEFORE the submit event. You should remove it and focus on the AJAX method.

Comment: @AndyMercer, can confirm that it appears to work. (using onsbmit in the <form> tag and appendRedundancy in the onClick of the submit button) I use it to clear the name field ready for the next submission, Google forms then pops up a tab with submission confirmation and my google sheet shows that the previously inputted name was submitted.

Comment: What you are saying isn't technically possible, @aName. The `submit` event fires before form submission. That is how AJAX works, because we hook into the `submit` event and run `event.preventDefault()`. The reason that is appears to work, is because Google Forms isn't using the browser's native submit functionality, but instead submitting via AJAX.